# Qt5: Font size too big when run in Gnome on Wayland

Tags: gnome, qt, wayland

I'm using the GNOME 3 with Wayland and it works fine except when running a Qt application. The application behaves strangly (partial rendering, placed below Top-Bar) and some fonts are huge (e.g. title and menu bar).

I've tried changing the Qt-Theme but this doesn't affect the font size. When using GNOME on X11 everything works fine.

Common logs:

```
Using Wayland-EGL
Using the 'xdg-shell-v6' shell integration
```

`QT_WAYLAND_SHELL_INTEGRATION=wl-shell` doesn't help much either.

[image: Screenshot of QtCreator]

PS: I assume it's related to the High DPI handling in Qt5: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html

**Update 19.6.2018:** It seems to be fixed in the QT5 realase (Archlinux) of today. It shows the following log message:
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.

Comment: Oh boy, more fallout from the horrible monstrosity that Gnome 3 is. Try Mate, it should work OOB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug introduces in 5.11. I found the corresponding bug in the [base release notes for 5.11.1](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/dist/changes-5.11.1/?h=v5.11.1): [QTBUG-68619](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68619)